# Does jacoco agent report code coverage for another agent's premain

Tags: java, jacoco, instrumentation, agent

For the scenario that run test against to an agent, and Jacoco agent is instrumented to this target agent. Will jacoco report code coverage for the target agent's premain method?

Comment: not clear what is the question.

Comment: @RamPrakash Every javaagent has a `premain` method where the JVM load the agent. I am asking, if I provide two agents, the first one is Jacoco, the second is another agent. Will the second agent's `premain` method be taken into account for the code coverage by jacoco agent

Answer (score 1):

Javaagents are applied in the order in which they are specified on the command line. If the JaCoCo agent is specified first, its instrumentation is applied to all agents that come after.

Therefore, if you want to include coverage of any code that a Java agents changes or adds, you should put these after JaCoCo.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I understood that if I want to get code coverage for another agent, I need specify jacoco agent first in the command line. But  my question is ask would the second agent's `premain` method be reported by jacoco agent for the code coverage? I tried an experiment in my local, I find the jacoco's report would not include the code coverage of second agent. Therefore, try to figure out whether jacoco agent would report this part or not?

Comment: @Y.Feng yes it will - I've added answer containing example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42480303/244993

Answer (score 1):

JaCoCo agent instruments and records execution of classes that are loaded after it. Java agents are loaded in the order in which they are specified on the command line. So if second agent is specified after JaCoCo agent, then JaCoCo will instrument it and record its execution. Here is example:

agent `src/main/java/Premain.java`:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Premain {
  public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

an empty test `src/test/java/Test.java` just to be able to execute agent with it, doesn't execute code of an agent directly:

```
import org.junit.Test

public class Test {
  @Test
  public void test() {
  }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <argLine>-javaagent:target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</argLine>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Premain-Class>Premain</Premain-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.9</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- to be able to use agent that was built -->
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Execution of `mvn clean jacoco:prepare-agent verify jacoco:report` will produce report in directory `target/site/jacoco`:

[image: report]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and brief demo! Very helpful!